# Relative Interface (TYPESCRIPT)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-redux

How can I make the state in ISetOpen with relative type of modal in ISetOpen?

Example:

**if ISetOpen.modal === 'payModal': ISetOpen.state = IPayModal**

**if ISetOpen.modal === 'deleteModal': ISetOpen.state = IDeleteModal**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface IPayModal {
  amount: number
  isOpen: boolean
}

interface IDeleteModal {
  id: number
  isOpen: boolean
}

export interface ModalsState {
  payModal: IPayModal
  deleteModal: IDeleteModal
}

const initialState: ModalsState = {
  payModal: {
    amount: 0,
    isOpen: false
  },
  deleteModal: {
    id: 0,
    isOpen: false
  }
}

interface ISetOpen {
  modal: keyof typeof initialState
  state: IPayModal | IDeleteModal
}

export const modalsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'modals',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setOpen: (state, action: PayloadAction<ISetOpen>) => {
      state[action.payload.modal] = action.payload.state
    }
  }
})

export const { setOpen } = modalsSlice.actions

export default modalsSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two properties in your current `ISetOpen` interface are both unions, but there is no relationship between the `modal` and the `state`.

What you want is a union of valid pairings of `modal` and `state`.  We can do this with mapped types.  For each key (`"payModal" | "deleteModal"`) we create an object with the specific `modal` and `state` for each type.

```
type ISetOpen = {
  [K in keyof ModalsState]: {
    modal: K;
    state: ModalsState[K]
  }
}[keyof ModalsState]
```

This resolves to

```
type ISetOpen = {
    modal: "payModal";
    state: IPayModal;
} | {
    modal: "deleteModal";
    state: IDeleteModal;
}
```

This will ensure that all of your actions are dispatched with the correct values.

Unfortunately it does not resolve the issues in the reducer, as `state[action.payload.modal]` is still evaluated as a union `state.payModal | state.deleteModal`.  You may need to use a type assertion here.  For example, `action.payload.state as IPayModal & IDeleteModal;`

Comment:  Tks my friend

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much are you attached to this `keyof typeof initialState`, especially in a case when there will be 3rd or more options there.

You can achieve what you want by converting your interface into union type:

```js
type ISetOpen = {
  modal: 'payModal';
  state: IPayModal;
} | {
  modal: 'deleteModal';
  state: IDeleteModal;
}
```

Comment: Is a valid answer, but would it be possible to make this less manual?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by that.

Comment: Make him less verbose